# HTML 5 Canvas, interact with HTML tags behind it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, element

Ok, so I have a HTML 5 canvas element on top of my website to overlay a snow effect.

I use this CSS to get the snow effect on top of the rest of the website:

```
#snow {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

What I'd like to do is get the snow interacting with elements on the page. e.g. If it hits a `<p>` tag, it will stop. So the snow gradually builds up on elements on the page.

How would I go about doing this? How do you get the locations of elements on a different layer with Javascript?

Comment: The snow at the top of the planetminecraft website has the shape of the logo specially coded in so the snow avoids it, it isn't interacting with the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is fairly straight-forwards.

- Collect the elements you want to interact with
- Extract the client-rect of each which represents each element's absolute position
- Update on scroll etc.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/5y2Yr/)

In this demo the red **squares representing DOM elements are drawn on the canvas**, not set by CSS. This to demonstrate the principle. What you can do with the code is to use these rectangles as collision objects instead with the snow.

Get the elements we want to interact with:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p'); /// all "P" elements
```

Now iterate through the collection and get the absolute boundary rectangle from each:

```
function getRects() {
    
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

        /// get rect for this element
        rect = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        
        /// use it for something, or store in an array etc.
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.left,
                       rect.top,
                       rect.width,
                       rect.height);
    }
}
```

(sorry, no snow demo but you should be able to use this to implement what you ask for).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this out and it worked perfectly. :-)

Comment: @hipkiss I'm sure there exists other ways, better or worse. You could make a "fake" collection animation by rendering the location, approx. or accurate, to a bg image, then grow the "snow" randomly the top-edge areas of where the elements would be.. it very much depends on your page, layout, look etc. To adopt to different resolutions and positions it will be difficult to avoid reading the locations dynamically on resize, scroll etc. but I think you could get away with an approximation, or even random accumulation (as long as the seeded areas are kept through resizes and so forth) as well.

Comment: @K3N Apologies. My use case is a lot simpler. I want to be able to normally navigate a webpage, underneath a canvas that allows the user to draw on it. Switching between I have, but switching between the two so the drawings remain in view whilst navigating around the website (on the same page, I know it would clear the canvas on a new page), is the difficult bit. Not figured it out yet.

Comment: @hipkiss you could look into single-page applications (SPA) or see if CSS page transitions can be useful (storing animation data in localStorage between each page).

Comment: @K3N That doesn't solve being able to navigate even a SPA whilst an annotation is present on the page?

Comment: @hipkiss I think you need to open this as new question and describe the problem more in-depth.}

Comment: @K3N https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013239/how-to-interact-with-html-behind-a-canvas :) Please let me know if it doesn't make sense. :/